# How to implement Intent in API 33

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio to convert/upgrade an app from API 29 to 33. API 33 produces (many) errors, some of which seem to be gradle related but there are bits of the Java code that are flagged as errors.
The original Intents no longer work in 33 and I cannot fathom the Google documentation.
These lines don't work;

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, UserSectionInput.class);
startActivity(i);
```

What would I use for 33?

Sorry if the code is a bit long but I wanted to show the full context

```
package com.silverfernsolutions.ansi360;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class SectionFileSelection extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_section_file_selection);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
    int Idx=0;
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn0: Idx=0 ;break;
        case R.id.btn1: Idx=1 ;break;
        case R.id.btn2: Idx=2 ;break;
        case R.id.btn3: Idx=3 ;break;
        case R.id.btn4: Idx=4 ;break;
        case R.id.btn5: Idx=5 ;break;
        case R.id.btn6: Idx=6 ;break;
        case R.id.btn7: Idx=7 ;break;

    } //end switch

    runIntents(Idx);

}//end onClick

private void runIntents(int idx){

    if (idx==0){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, UserSectionInput.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else{
       Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowSelectedSource.class);
       i.putExtra("ButtonID",idx);
       startActivity(i);
    } //endif


}//end runintents
```

}

Comment: `These lines don't work;` Of course they still work. What exactly do you think does not work,? Any errors,? Exceptions,? Blank screens?

Comment: Agreed, those lines look perfectly normal for a Java Android app, regardless of API level.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I must be something missing as the (this, UserSectionInput.class) is underscored with a squigly red line and the startActivity is in red (bold).